# How to POST multiple xml to a WebService

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, post, httpwebrequest

Actually I have the code in c# to do an httpwebrequest with a POST method sending one XML and receiving an XML answer and saving it, here is the code:

```
public static XmlDocument PostXMLTransaction(string v_strURL)
{
//Declare XMLResponse document
XmlDocument XMLResponse = null;

//Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebRequest class.
HttpWebRequest objHttpWebRequest;

//Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebResponse class
HttpWebResponse objHttpWebResponse = null;

//Declare a generic view of a sequence of bytes
Stream objRequestStream = null;
Stream objResponseStream = null;

//Declare XMLReader
XmlTextReader objXMLReader;

//Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL.
objHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(v_strURL);

try
{
//---------- Start HttpRequest 

//Set HttpWebRequest properties
byte[] bytes;
bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("C:\\Documents\ \Aplicacion1\\Aplicacion1\\absisSIHttpProfileTO.xm l");
objHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
objHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
objHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";

//Get Stream object 
objRequestStream = objHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();

//Writes a sequence of bytes to the current stream 
objRequestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

//Close stream
objRequestStream.Close();

//---------- End HttpRequest

//Sends the HttpWebRequest, and waits for a response.
objHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

//---------- Start HttpResponse
if (objHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
//Get response stream 
objResponseStream = objHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

//Load response stream into XMLReader
objXMLReader = new XmlTextReader(objResponseStream);

//Declare XMLDocument
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(objXMLReader);
xmldoc.Save(@"C:\Documents\Aplicacion1\Aplicacion1\myxml.xml");

//Set XMLResponse object returned from XMLReader
XMLResponse = xmldoc;

//Close XMLReader
objXMLReader.Close();
}

//Close HttpWebResponse
objHttpWebResponse.Close();
}
catch (WebException we)
{
//TODO: Add custom exception handling
throw new Exception(we.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
//Close connections
objRequestStream.Close();
objResponseStream.Close();
objHttpWebResponse.Close();

//Release objects
objXMLReader = null;
objRequestStream = null;
objResponseStream = null;
objHttpWebResponse = null;
objHttpWebRequest = null;
}

//Return
return XMLResponse;
}
```

Mi question now is how can I send multiple XML as parameters in one httpwebrequest?

Like:
public static XmlDocument PostXMLTransaction(xmldocument xml1, xmldocument xml2)

Comment: BTW, you are not sending xml in your code, you are just sending the string `C:\\Documents\ \Aplicacion1\\Aplicacion1\\absisSIHttpProfileTO.xm l`

Comment: This code: objHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
objHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
objHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'"; It's not for sending XML?

Comment: `bytes` contains `c:\\documents.....` string, not the file content

Comment: And how can I send a httpwebrequest with a xml as parameter?

Comment: Read the file content into `bytes` (StreamReader,File, FileStream etc.)

Comment: Well, I've declared a Stream objRequestStream where I read the bytes, It's not correct? objRequestStream = objHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(); objRequestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

Comment: Your problem lies in filling `bytes` variable. Debug your code and see what you are writing to `objRequestStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that relies on your protocol really. The server on the other side needs to know how to handle multiple messages over 1 connection. If the server is a http webserver than your lucky since that protocol already defines a mechanism of reusing a connection. (Although both the client and the server have to agree on using this).

For this, you can play with the KeepAlive property of HttpWebRequest, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive.aspx